# Using iterated integrals compute the area of the set $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, when $D$ is bounded by $y=\frac12 x^2$ and $y=2x.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Using iterated integrals compute the area of the set $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, when $D$ is bounded by $y=\frac12 x^2$ and $y=2x.$

So I need to compute $\iint_D 1 \ dy \ dx$ right?

It's easy to see that the intersection of the parabola and the line is at $x=4$ and $y=8$.

Thus should I integrate $$\iint_D 1 \ dy \ dx = \int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{2x}1 \ dy \ dx = 16?$$

I'm quite confused by the term iterated integral? I assume they mean just a double integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find area bound between two given curves so your lower bound should be $y = \frac{1}{2}x^2$. The way you have set up, you will get the area of the triangle bound by line $\,y = 2x$ and $x$-axis for $0 \leq x \leq 4$.

$\displaystyle \iint_D 1 \ dy \ dx = \int_{0}^{4}\int_{x^2/2}^{2x}1 \ dy \ dx$

Here is a sketch

[image]